# Ocaml buffer modification specific position

Tags: ocaml, string-concatenation

I'm currently building/concatenating pretty big strings in a program I'm developing. To give some context, the full string has the size of a terminal. This happens quite a lot since I'm developing a terminal application. I found the datastructure `Buffer`, which seems to be the most performant way to concatenate strings with the standard library.

Is this the right choice if I also frequently need to update some part of a buffer at a specific position? Let's say character 20 to 50 ?
Is there a better way in this case?

Comment: Gap buffers & co: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169440/text-editor-theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICS, there is no way to alter the contents of a `Buffer.t` except adding to the end. Maybe you should take a look at the module `Bytes`. A `Bytes.t` is mutable everywhere, only the length cannot change. But it seems the length you need is fixed anyway: the size of the terminal (and if the terminal window is resized you can replace the `Bytes.t` by a new one).

Answer (score 4):

@coredump and @kne have given good answers. I might just add that in today's world a byte is a poor representation of a character. So you might consider using an array or a bigarray.

Comment: Why is `byte` a poor representation of a character? What's the advantage of array/bigarray?

Comment: The terminals I use (which are all software) can display any Unicode character. So the characters are represented by something like 21 bits each. The advantage of array and bigarray is that they can have elements large enough to hold 21 bits.